# How to convert object (print image CMYK) picture to true RGB value?

Tags: python, java, opencv

## Explanation

CMYK(RGB format) I don't know what the real term for this situation

If you print out RGB on a piece of paper it will look different with what computer is showing because it's in CMYK format.

Then you take picture of that piece of paper, it's store as RGB Format but all the color is still different from the computer screen.

As a result of that it remain the color of the printer (CMYK) but in RGB format as a picture in phone.

## Question

Don't worry about external factor... assume we're in perfect control environment.

So how can I convert phone picture of that piece of paper color to be as same as possible to what my computer is showing?

Can anyone share some theories or sample code to me below as answer?

## Example

Picture taken with a phone camera of a piece of printed paper color

[image]

What showing in my computer

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "CMYK(rgb format)"?

Comment: If you print out RGB on a piece of paper it will look different with what computer is showing because it's in CMYK format. Then you take picture of that piece of paper, it's store as RGB Format. I not really know what is call so I called it CMYK(RGB format). Because all the color is still different from the computer screen.

Comment: Yes, and it will always be different. Setting aside the CYMK to/from RGB transformations, if you take a picture of the printed paper with a camera you'll have a bunch of not-software-related factors to account for: Lighting, camera sensor quirks, paper color, etc.

Comment: Don't worry about Lighting, camera sensor quirks, paper color, etc. How can I convert it?

Comment: You have two RGB images (the camera one and the original one), which have some color difference. The "conversion" from one to the other is done by adding for each pixel a correction factor (3 values: dR, dG, dB). This correction factor must be estimated by you either comparing enough images and trying to figure out how the printer/camera pair affects the colors (and it most likely will be color-dependent). How to do that is a design choice you need to make (neural netowrks? statistical analysis of pixel color deviations? Something else altogether?) and is not a code-related question.

Comment: @halfer I don't think my post is any good just delete it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have permissions to delete it @Yau. I expect you do, using the links next to `share | edit | close` etc. However, since you have received two apparently helpful answers, I would suggest you consider _not_ deleting it, since it is not nice to invalidate and remove other people's kind work. That said, if you have permissions to delete, it means you are technically permitted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The "color gamut", the set of colors that can be accurately represented, differs between RGB and CMYK. Even with the best (4-color process) printer in the world, you won't be able to represent, e.g., the same bright green that you can on a monitor.

Comment: I came up with a theory before posting this question. I will develop a prototype on Monday and see whether it can be a applicable solution.

Answer (score 0):

the colors you used in your example are "fully saturated" colours and hence can't be represented in the other space, if you pick less saturated colors you should have more luck

as @Sneftel said, they have different Gamuts and hence you can't convert between every colour in either space

that said, you could look at libraries like [colormath](https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that lets you do simple things like:

```
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, CMYKColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

convert_color(sRGBColor(1, 1, 0), CMYKColor)
```

but to actually convert between real images and photos of these images, you'd need a very controlled environment.  the above code has non-physical assumptions, but I think you should be able to get there using other intermediate colorspaces and maybe the CIECAM02 model

Comment: Thank You for sharing colormath, I never heard before. I will look into it.